# elasticsearch + python substring search in array of strings

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have 10k+ records in elastic search. one of the fields(dept) holds data in form of array

eg records are

```
{
        "username": "tom",
        "dept": [
            "cust_service",
            "sales_rpr",
            "store_in",
        ],
        "location": "NY"
}



{
        "username": "adam",
        "dept": [
            "cust_opr",
            "floor_in",
            "mg_cust_opr",
        ],
        "location": "MA"
}
.
.
.
```

I want to do autocomplete on `dept` field, if user search for `cus` it should return

```
["cust_service", "cust_opr", "mg_cust_opr"]
```

With best match at the top

I have made the query

```
query = {
            "_source": [],
            "size": 0,
            "min_score": 0.5,
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "wildcard": {
                                "dept": {
                                    "value": "*cus*"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "filter": [],
                    "should": [],
                    "must_not": []
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "auto_complete": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": f"dept.raw",
                        "size": 20,
                        "order": {"max_score": 'desc'}
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "max_score": {
                            "avg": {"script": "_score"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

It is not giving [`"cust_service", "cust_opr", "mg_cust_opr"]` instead gives other answers which are irrelevant to search key(cus). but when field is just `string` instead of `array` it is giving the result as expected.

How do i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What ```other answers``` is it giving? For more understanding.

Comment: @JishanShaikh it is giving 20 results from dept field only but it doesn't include "cus" result

Comment: You missed double-quotes in the wildcard for dept.?

Comment: @JishanShaikh that was typo while writing. updated it. except that, any idea why am I not getting the desired result?

Comment: Try removing filter, should, and must_not. Empty should and must_not may behave arbitrarily.